# What is the right R idiom to reclassify elements in a datafrmae without using ifelse

Tags: r, tidyverse

So assume we have a set of vectors that contain types of products:

```
library(tidyverse)
c("bramley", "cox", "winesap", "cortland") -> apples
c("malbec", "solaris", "shiraz", "merlot") -> wines
```

Assume we have a tibble that contains stock types in a warehouse:

```
tibble(
  stock = c("bramley", "malbec", "solaris", "merlot")
) ->
  warehouse_stock
```

Now suppose we want to add an element to the warehouse stock identifying the stock type of these elements, what I have done in the past is this:

```
warehouse_stock %>%
  mutate(
    stock_type = ifelse(stock %in% apples, "Food",
                        ifelse(stock %in% wines, "Drink", "unknown"))
  ) ->
  warehouse_stock
```

This works fine for when there are only two stock types but would quickly become unmanageable as the stock types grew. What would be a more readable way of doing this, is there anything in the tidyverse that does this?

Comment: Just going to put it here: `case_when` is a nice tidyverse alternative to stacked `ifelse`.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 thanks that is useful to know and will be what I use going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd turn the lookups into a separate table and use a join to accomplish this:

```
key <- list(
    apples = c("bramley", "cox", "winesap", "cortland"), 
    wines = c("malbec", "solaris", "shiraz", "merlot")
) %>%
    {tibble(
         stock = unlist(., use.names = FALSE),
         stock_type = rep(names(.), lengths(.))
     )}


warehouse_stock %>%
    left_join(key, by = "stock")
```

Gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  stock   stock_type
  <chr>   <chr>     
1 bramley apples    
2 malbec  wines     
3 solaris wines     
4 merlot  wines
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding your original code using `case_when()`, which is a `tidyverse` neat alternative to stacked `ifelse()`:

```
warehouse_stock %>%
  mutate(stock_type = case_when(stock %in% apples ~ "Food",
                                stock %in% wines ~ "Drink",
                                TRUE ~ "unknown")) ->  warehouse_stock
```

It will be useful if the stock types are small or not going to change over time. If the number of stock types are large, I defer to the [answer by @Tyler Rinker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61838849/11316205) that is much better and much easier to maintain in the long run.